# How to install npm to work on github

Tags: node.js, github, npm, npm-install

I am new to **github**. I want to install **npm** to work with **node js**. But while installing `npm` i am getting the below error. I cloned my project from GitHub. After cloning is done, I need to install `npm` to build my project. But I am failing in installing the `npm`.

Anyone please suggest an idea to solve this.

**Error Image:**

[image]

I tried everything what i surfed. But i didn't find any solution for this.

Comment: Are you sure you have node-gyp installed on your machine?

Comment: yes, I got node gyp installed. Still i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

A compiler is required to build native modules (C, C++) on windows.
Your error occurs when node-gyp tries to build the "bignum" module.

Take a look on the [node-gyp Readme](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp). 
The installation of a compiler on windows is described there.

Comment: Looks like OpenSSL needs to be installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doc help https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node. Node comes with npm installed so you should have a version of npm.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that one package is using openSSL and need openssl header files to be installed. 
You need to install openssl AND! the header files to your windows. And also be sure the search path to the header files is set correctly.

Sorry here, I'm not familiar anymore with windows. On MacOS or Linux I could help you.

But may the official openssl [documentation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) help you.